# MongoDB Dedupe and Sort using Reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, reduce

I'm using `Reduce` to create a joined `String` of `field`s from an `array`.

For example, let's say I have an `array` of `subdocuments` called `children` - and each `child` has a `name` `field`.

e.g

```
[
   {name:"Zak"}, {name:"Bob"}, {name:"Sharon"}, {name:"Zak"}, {name:"Cindy"}, {name:"Bob"}, {name:"Peter"}
]
```

The `expression` below will give me a "csv" of `"Zak, Bob, Sharon, Zak, Cindy, Bob, Peter, "`;

(Yes - I know I can use `$cond` to detect the last iteration and remove the `trail`ing `", "`.

```
  uniqueCsv: {
   $reduce: {
     input: "$children",
     initialValue: '',
     in: {
       $concat: ["$$this.name", ", ", "$$value"]
     }
   }
  }
```

Is it possible to `dedupe` and `sort` with this `reduce` so that we can have

`"Bob, Cindy, Peter, Sharon, Zak"` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$setUnion` to get unique elements from `children.name` and this will sort string in ascending order
- `$concat` to pass first parameter as `$$value` and second as condition if value is empty then return empty otherwise ", " and third as `$$this` means current string

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      uniqueCsv: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $setUnion: "$children.name" },
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value", ""] }, "", ", "] },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S6u9WqbsV_E)

---

Second approach using `$substr` instead of `$cond`

- `$substr` to pass current reduce operation, reduce operation will return `, Bob, Cindy, Peter, Sharon, Zak`
- now we just need to remove first 2 character from above string, second parameter to start string from 2 second position and third parameter to pass length of string -1 will return all strings

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      uniqueCsv: {
        $substr: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: { $setUnion: "$children.name" },
              initialValue: "",
              in: {
                $concat: ["$$value", ", ", "$$this"]
              }
            }
          },
          2,
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pTVkPJZp8ME)

> **Warning:**
>
> As per MongoDB *`$setUnion`: The order of the elements in the output array is unspecified.*

> but as per my experience it return array of string in ascending order, i have used it in my projects as well, i have tested it every way but it gives 100% ascending order.
>
> It is your choice to use this in your project or not without mongodb confirmation.

Comment: I prefer `$cond` to `substr` in this case, but appreciate both methods. `$setUnion` seems like a great way to handle the `dedupe`. I verified it sorts `asc` in your playgrounds, but how do you know this? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#behavior states that "`$setUnion ignores the order of the elements" and "The order of the elements in the output array is unspecified."

Comment: i have updated the reason it may help you.

Comment: Seems to work with my data. Not the biggest deal in edge cases where it fails and I trust you. Thanks!